# Is there a restaurant outside baggage claim, BOS Terminal E?

Tags: bos

I will be taking a bus from New Hampshire round trip to Boston Logan airport (BOS). The plane will land back at BOS two hours before the next available bus ride. Is there any restaurant option by the baggage claim area? I will be checking a bag so I will need to leave the secure area but cannot leave the airport.

Comment: I prefer to take the bus to South Station and get the Silver Line to and from Logan. There are more restaurants there, and it's (relatively) cheaper.

Answer (score 3):

The [airport website](http://www.massport.com/logan-airport/) has a [list of restaurants](http://www.massport.com/logan-airport/dining-shopping/restaurants/) sorted by terminal and pre/post security.  As pre-security restaurants in Terminal E, it lists the Dine Boston Restaurant and Cafe, described by Google as "Modern, informal spot with a New England–inspired menu, including thin-crust pizza & other pub grub".  There is also a Dunkin Donuts.

You could also go to another terminal for more options.  There is a [free shuttle](http://www.massport.com/logan-airport/to-from-logan/transportation-options/on-airport-shuttle/).

Comment: I ate at Dine Boston Restaurant last July when my train got me to Logan with 1.5 hours to kill before my airline began check-in.  They were quite accommodating of the fact that a lot of their customers have luggage with them. The food is, I would say, unremarkable as far as American airport food goes—but you could certainly do much, much worse.  Note that the restaurant is not "by the baggage claim area" *per se* but is instead upstairs in the departures hall.